# How does one bind commands to combinations of non-control key presses in Sublime?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Let's say, as an example, I want to expand the functionality of the arrow keys. When I press ctrl+z in combination with an arrow key it performs either a redo, undo, soft redo, or soft undo, depending on the direction of the arrow I press. I've prototyped this and it feels very intuitive (well, to be fair, I'm actually using vim-style hjkl navigation instead of arrow keys, but that's an aside):

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+z+left"], "command": "undo"},
    { "keys": ["ctrl+z+right"], "command": "redo"}
]
```

The problem arises when I try to press ctrl+left/right, without the z. I should expect this to  move the cursor left or right by one word, but instead it performs the undo/redo that I've just recently binded.

Now, I know full well I could do this instead:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+z","ctrl+left"], "command": "undo"},
    { "keys": ["ctrl+z","ctrl+right"], "command": "redo"}
]
```

But it just doesn't feel the same.

How can I bind ctrl+z+left/right without modifying the behavior of ctrl+left/right?

Comment: How about embracing the constraints instead of fighting them and use `ctrl+super+...` instead of `ctrl+z+...`?

Comment: If I can get this to work, it allows for a much greater range of key combinations while at the same time adding some sense of order to them. I could just as well setup a ctrl+f+arrow to find next or previous, a ctrl+d+arrow to extend existing ctrl+d functionality, a ctrl+tab+arrow to change tabs, or a set of additional combinations to fold/unfold, go to bookmarks, go to mispellings, etc. Similar behavior could be done with number keys, e.g. to move down a given number of lines/words/subwords/code blocks, or fold by a given level.

Comment: Completely agree, and asking does no harm, but I don't think it is possible and no-one seems to be rushing forward to prove me wrong, which both of us would welcome, so it may well be one of those things that would cool if things were different, but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came to was to create my own plugin. The plugin tracks previous key commands and redirects to other commands based upon their values. Its available on package manager as "[ContextualMove](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ContextualMove)"

Here's the plugin in its simplest form:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin, datetime

class ContextualMoveCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, context = None, direction = None, extend = False, timeout = 15):
        if not hasattr(self, 'context'):    self.context = context
        if not hasattr(self, 'timeout'):    self.timeout = timeout
        if not hasattr(self, 'lasttime'):   self.lasttime = datetime.datetime.now()

        DIRECTION_COMMANDS = { 
            None:   
            {
                'up':   {'command': 'move', 'args':{'by': 'lines', 'forward': False, 'extend': extend}},
                'down': {'command': 'move', 'args':{'by': 'lines', 'forward': True, 'extend': extend}},
                'left': {'command': 'move', 'args':{'by': 'characters', 'forward': False, 'extend': extend}},
                'right':{'command': 'move', 'args':{'by': 'characters', 'forward': True, 'extend': extend}}
            },
            'words':    
            {
                'up':   {"command": "move", "args": {'by': 'lines', 'forward': False, 'extend': extend} },
                'down': {"command": "move", "args": {'by': 'lines', 'forward': True, 'extend': extend} },
                'left': {'command': 'move', 'args':{'by': 'subwords', 'forward': False, 'extend': extend}},
                'right':{'command': 'move', 'args':{'by': 'subword_ends', 'forward': True, 'extend': extend}}
            },
            'lines':    
            {
                'up':   {"command": "move", "args": {'by': 'pages', 'forward': False, 'extend': extend} },
                'down': {"command": "move", "args": {'by': 'pages', 'forward': True, 'extend': extend} },
                'left': {'command': 'move_to', "args": {"to": "bol", 'extend': extend}},
                'right':{'command': 'move_to', "args": {"to": "eol", 'extend': extend}}
            },
            'scroll':   
            {
                'up':   {"command": "scroll_lines", "args": {"amount": 1.0 } },
                'down': {"command": "scroll_lines", "args": {"amount": -1.0 } },
                'left': {"command": "scroll_lines", "args": {"amount": 1.0 } },
                'right':{"command": "scroll_lines", "args": {"amount": -1.0 } }
            },
            'history':  
            {
                'up':   {'command': 'undo', 'args':{}},
                'down': {'command': 'redo', 'args':{}},
                'left': {'command': 'soft_undo', 'args':{}},
                'right':{'command': 'soft_redo', 'args':{}}
            },
            'indent':   
            {
                'up':   {'command': 'undo', 'args':{}},
                'down': {'command': 'redo', 'args':{}},
                'left': {'command': 'soft_undo', 'args':{}},
                'right':{'command': 'soft_redo', 'args':{}}
            },
            'tabs':     
            {
                'up':   {'command': 'prev_view_in_stack', 'args':{}},
                'down': {'command': 'next_view_in_stack', 'args':{}},
                'left': {'command': 'prev_view', 'args':{}},
                'right':{'command': 'next_view', 'args':{}}
            },
            'find':     
            {
                'up':   {'command': 'find_prev', 'args':{} },
                'down': {'command': 'find_next', 'args':{} },
                'left': {'command': 'find_prev', 'args':{} },
                'right':{'command': 'find_next', 'args':{} }
            }
        }

        CONTEXT_COMMANDS = {
            'find': {"command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "find", "reverse": False} } 
        }


        if not direction:
            if self.context == context:
                self.context = None
            else:
                self.context = context

            if self.context in CONTEXT_COMMANDS:
                command = CONTEXT_COMMANDS[self.context]
                self.window.run_command(command['command'], command['args'])

            return


        # time = datetime.datetime.now()
        # if (time - self.lasttime).seconds > self.timeout:
            # self.lasttime = time
            # self.context = None


        if self.context not in DIRECTION_COMMANDS:
            return

        context_commands = DIRECTION_COMMANDS[self.context]

        if direction not in context_commands:
            return

        command = context_commands[direction]

        self.window.run_command(command['command'], command['args'])
```

And here's the edits I made to key bindings:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+u"], "command": "contextual_move", "args": {"context": "history"} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+space"], "command": "contextual_move", "args": {"context": "words"} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+enter"], "command": "contextual_move", "args": {"context": "lines"} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+tab"], "command": "contextual_move", "args": {"context": "tabs"} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+f"], "command": "contextual_move", "args": {"context": "find"} },

{ "keys": ["ctrl+i"], "command": "contextual_move", "args": {"direction": "up"} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+k"], "command": "contextual_move", "args": {"direction": "down"} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+j"], "command": "contextual_move", "args": {"direction": "left"} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+l"], "command": "contextual_move", "args": {"direction": "right"} },

{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+i"], "command": "contextual_move", "args": {"direction": "up", "extend": true} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+k"], "command": "contextual_move", "args": {"direction": "down", "extend": true} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+j"], "command": "contextual_move", "args": {"direction": "left", "extend": true} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+l"], "command": "contextual_move", "args": {"direction": "right", "extend": true} },
```